# How to remove extra line breaks and invisible chars in ant

Tags: string, ant

Currently, I have a string which contains several lines (break via CR or CRLF or both), and each line might be invisible or empty or has invisible prefix or suffix chars.

I want to know how to remove the extra line breaks and trim the invisible chars via ant.

Comment: This is most likely an issue consuming windows files on Linux? In that case checkout the fixcrlf ant task, designed to handle this. See: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fixcrlf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about Ant [`filterchains`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html). You can use the following to trim lines and remove empty lines:

```
 <copy file="${input.file}" toFile="${output.file}">
    <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
            <deletecharacters chars="\t"/>
            <trim/>
            <ignoreblank/>
        </tokenfilter>
    </filterchain>
</copy>
```

Comment: I'd add `<fixcrlf>` as filter (and likely drop `ignoreblanks` and `deletechars`).